# Number of graphs having a specific structure

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $\mathcal{N} = \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ and $\mathcal{N}^i = \mathcal{N}\setminus \{i\} $. For each $i \in \mathcal{N}$ and for each $S \subset \mathcal{N}^i$, we have  a vertex $C_i^S$. For example, if $\mathcal{N} = \{1,2,3\}$, then we have $C_1^{\varnothing}, C_1^{\{2\}},C_1^{\{3\}}, C_1^{\{2,3\}}$, $C_2^{\varnothing}, C_2^{\{1\}},C_2^{\{3\}}, C_2^{\{1,3\}}$, and $C_3^{\varnothing}, C_3^{\{1\}},C_3^{\{2\}}, C_3^{\{1,2\}}$.

Vertices $C_k^{S_k}$, $k \in K \subset \mathcal{N}$ can form a graph (denote it by $[C_k^{S_k}, k \in K]$) if $i \in \bigcap_{k \neq i}S_k$ for each $i \in K$ (Note that two vertices with the same subscripts cannot be in a graph). For example, if $\mathcal{N} = \{1,2,3\}$, then $[C_1^{\{2\}}]$ and $[C_1^{\{2,3\}},C_2^{\{1\}}]$ are two of possible graphs.

Is it possible to find the number of possible graphs? Is it possible to find the number of possible graphs for each $N$? For example if $\mathcal{N} = \{1,2\}$, then $[C_1^{\{2\}}]$, $[C_2^{\{1\}}]$, $[C_1^{\{2\}}, C_2^{\{1\}}]$, $[C_1^{\varnothing}]$, $[C_2^{\varnothing}]$ are all possible graphs.

Comment: @bof Because for any two $C_i^{S_i}$ and $C_j^{S_j}$, we can have an edge between these two vertices if $i \in S_j$ and $j \in S_i$ and I want the number of possible connected graphs. But, knowing this doesn't help, so I simplified the problem and eliminated that part.

Comment: @bof exactly, is there any way to compute that number for each $N$?

Comment: @EricTowers You are right. The description was not clear. I edited the question.

Comment: @bof : Answers go in Answers, not comments.

Comment: @bof I agree with your description, that is correct. But I didn't get how you translate that to your suggested formula. Can you explain more?

Comment: @bof : I don't see a clear question that can be answered by improving the question.  I see a proposed answer with a question mark appended to it.  If you have a question about the specification, you should ask about the specification.  Even better is to frame your question as an A/B dichotomy so that what is unclear and how it is to be made clear is trivially extracted from your comment.

Comment: @bof The part you have $2^{(N-k)k}$. Why?

Comment: @bof the number of choices for each $S_i$ is $2^{N-k}$ because $S_i$ should have at least $k$ members?

Comment: @bof Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\binom Nk2^{(N-k)k}.$$

First choose a number $k\in\{1,\dots,N\},$ the number of vertices.

Next choose a $k$-element set $K\subseteq\{1,\dots,N\}.$

For each $i\in K$ choose a set $S_i\subseteq\{1,\dots,N\}$ subject to the conditon that $S_i\cap K=K\setminus\{i\}.$ In other words, $S_i=(K\setminus\{i\})\cup T$ where $T$ is an arbitrary subset of $N\setminus K;$ there are $2^{N-k}$ choices for $T$ and so $2^{N-k}$ choices for $S_i.$

Since there are $k$ elements in $K,$ there are $\left(2^{N-k}\right)^k=2^{(N-k)k}$ ways to choose all the sets $S_i,\ i\in K.$

Comment: I am looking to expand the $2^{(N-k)k}$. For $N=4, k=2$, we have 
$2^{2 \times 2} = 16$ and $\sum_{l_1=0}^{N-k} \sum_{l_2=0}^{N-k} {N-k \choose l_1} {N-k \choose l_2} = \sum_{l_1=0}^{2} \sum_{l_2=0}^{2} {2 \choose l_1} {2 \choose l_2} = 16$. So, I think $2^{(N-k)k} = 
\sum_{l_1=0}^{N-k} \ldots \sum_{l_k=0}^{N-k} {N-k \choose l_1}\times \ldots  \times {N-k \choose l_k}$. Am I right?

Comment: Now to further explore $2^{(N-k)k}$, I want to count similar choices together and by similar I mean for example $ {2 \choose l_1} {2 \choose l_2}$ and $ {2 \choose l_2} {2 \choose l_1}$. So one way to do that is to write it as $\sum_{l_1=0}^{2} \sum_{l_2=l_1}^{2} {2 \choose l_1} {2 \choose l_2} f(l_1,l_2) = 16$. What I know for $f(l_1,l_2)$ is that it is equal to $\dfrac{2!}{1!1!}$ if $l_1 \neq l_2$ and $\dfrac{2!}{2!}$ if $l_1 = l_2$. What we can say about function $f$ in the case of general $k$?